# Can't pass variable to predefined function in RubyMine Live Template

Tags: rubymine, live-templates

I am trying to create a live template where the second variable is simply an uppercased version of the first variable. The predefined function `capitalize(String)` seems like exactly what I need but I am at a loss as to how to actually pass the variable in. Every time I try to set the parameter in the expression, it just resets to `String`.

Template Format:
[image: template format]

What I think should work:
[image]

But every time I tab out of the field, it just reverts to:
[image]

How do I get `class` to take `instance` as input and capitalize it?

Comment: What RubyMine version do you use? (I didn't catch this behaviour in the last 8.0.2)

Comment: @Olivia I was using 8.0.1 when I posted this. The same behavior remains in 8.0.2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution is to hit the OK button with your mouse after setting the field. Do not hit enter or tab.

Credit: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-132965#comment=27-850938

Answer (score 3):

It appears to be a known issue, please vote for it:

https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-132965

In addition, there is a request for rethinking this dialog:

https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-146698

So at the moment you may hit 'Enter' after changing the parameter from 'String' to 'instance' (it will be applied) or type the whole expression manually.

Comment: Hitting enter does not work. The solution as explained on the tracker is to not hit any keys and instead click OK with the mouse while still in that field.

Comment: Hit "Enter" in parameter textbox is working,and only this will work,thanks. My IDEA version is 2017.2.