# Is it possible to chain predefined functions in RubyMine live templates?

Tags: rubymine, jetbrains-ide, live-templates

I want to be able to chain live template predefined functions so the output of one can be used as the input of another, like so:

```
underscoresToSpaces(fileNameWithoutExtension())
```

I have a (perhaps false) memory of having been able to do this before, but can't manage to get it to work again.

I am using RubyMine 8.0.3.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Chaining predefined functions in RubyMine live templates works for me in a straightforward way. Defining this live template in Preferences → Editor → Live Templates

[image]

and typing fws in an editor inserts the file's name without spaces.

Current RubyMine (I'm using 8.0.3 too) has [a bug which causes a template variable's expression to not be saved properly if you tab out of the expression field.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34443900/1337796) Work around it by clicking OK after entering the expression.

Comment: I was doing the exact steps you suggest, but as part of a larger template. I tried to recreate your MVCE and noticed the expression was not saving correctly (I presume due to http://stackoverflow.com/a/34443900/1337796) but once I got it working, I tried the same steps on the original, larger template and it's now working. So I am not sure what has changed, but it now seems to be functioning correctly, if a little unreliably due to the linked issue above. Thanks.